# Access var from rootViewController in CollectionViewCell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to access a variable from my rootViewController from within a different viewController (it‘s a CollectionViewCell).

```
window!.rootViewController = ViewController()
```

I declare the var like so:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var testString : String = "Test";

    override func viewDidLoad() {    
[…]
```

And try to access it this way:

```
import UIKit

class MainCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        […]
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let mainView = self.window!.rootViewController
        var testStringFromMainView = mainView.test
[…]
```

But all I keep getting is:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

Strange thing is, when I try for example

```
mainView.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

it works.

I can’t figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must conditionally cast the rootViewController. Your current code only knows that it is a UIViewController, but in order for it to use your variable, it needs to know that it is an instance of your subclassed view controller, `ViewController`.

Replacing your `MainCollectionViewCell.init` with this should fix the problem:

```
if let cvc = self.window!.rootViewController as? ViewController {
    var testStringFromMainView = cvc.test
}
```

Please note that due to the conditional unwrapping, which is much safer than forced unwrapping, this code will not be executed if the `rootViewController` is not an instance of class `ViewController`. In other words, you need to look into global variables if your app will have multiple view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `rootViewController` is a type of `UIViewController` and doesn't have a `test` property. Anyway, that doesn't matter as you shouldn't be trying to do what you're trying to do - it isn't appropriate for the cell to be trying to navigate up to the root view controller. Anything you need in the cell should be passed (see dependency injection) from the root view controller 'down' to through the view controllers to the cell. In this way your code is logical and the dependencies are obvious. What you're trying to do is hide a dependency in the bottom of your view hierarchy. You can make it work (with a cast), but you shouldn't.

Comment: What would be the best practice if I have a button within the cell, that when touched should change the property of my rootViewController? How can I pass this event up?

Comment: Notification or some form of delegation, but why is it on the root view controller?

Comment: I need to change constraints that are placed on the root view controller (but affect the CollectionView’s size) … Calling a function of the root view controller that does this would also work, but I guess that would be the same inappropriate way as the one I planned to use.

Comment: I’m having that problem over and over again – I need to trigger the changing of constraints of a parent view from within the children views that are affected by these constraints and I am looking for a clean way to do that.

Comment: intrinsic content size